# AngularJS: Cookies should be passed only for certain request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cookies

In my application, I don't want the (stale) cookies to be passed as part of the first request. While the cookies should be passed in all subsequent requests to establish a session. Is it possible to provide configuration at $http request, so that cookies are not passed along with the request.

I have enabled cookies using $httpProvider:

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

But this enables cookies for all the request. Please provide a mechanism by which I can disable cookies for a particular $http request.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to override the default behavior like this:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/yourUrl', headers: {'Authorization' : 'SomeNewValue'} })
```